Error: ParentContainsErrorRecordException?
Tried the below code but getting an error with it?
Param(
    [string]$InputFilePath = "C:\Temp\mock1.xlsx",
    [string]$OutputFilePath = "C:\Temp\mockresult.xlsx",
    [string[]]$EMNames
)

At line:12 char:30 [string]$InputFilePath = "C:\Temp\mock1.xlsx", The assignment expression is not valid. Then input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.
CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide

Is the parameter block the first block in your script? (I guess not as the error says line 12...)

You'll have to put the 'Param' section right on top of your script, I guess that'll fix it.
Greetings Johann
